# Checking array against another array

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have the following two arrays:

```
$array = Array("Julie","Clive","Audrey","Tom","Jim","Ben","Dave","Paul");
$mandt = Array(1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1);
```

The numbers signify whether the names are valid or not. 1 is valid 0 is not. I need to check through the names and `echo` their name and then `"true"` if the name is valid and `"false"` if it is not, i.e:

> Julie: True
>   Clive: False
>   Audry: False

Etc...

Could anybody help me out please?

THanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So something like this `foreach()` loop?...

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    echo $value.": ";
    echo $mandt[$key] ? "True" : "False";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for($i=0, $count=count($array); $i<$count; $i++){
    echo $array[$i] . ": " . ($mandt[$i]? "True":"False") . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: for little optimization, you can store `$cnt = count($array);` then use in for loop

Answer (score 2):

```
$values = array_combine($array, $mandt);
$values = array_map(function ($i) { return $i ? 'True' : 'False'; }, $values);

var_dump($values);

// or loop through them, or whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just loop through the arrays?

```
$array = Array("Julie","Clive","Audrey","Tom","Jim","Ben","Dave","Paul");
$mandt = Array(1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1);

$c = count($array);
for ($i = 0; i < $c; i++) {
  echo $array[$i] . ": " . (($mandt[$i] == 1)?"True":"False") . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping and comparing the arrays, you could make a Hashtable-like array, like this:

```
$arr = array(
    "Julie" => true,
    "Clive" => false,
    "Audrey" => false,
     "Tom" => true
     [...]
);
```

This way, you can just run something like that:

```
if ($arr["Julie"]) {
    //Julie is a valid name!
} else {
    //Julie is not a valid name!
}
```

This would be way more efficient than looping through the array.